# Why am I getting an unwanted result while making a dictionary via list of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

```
x = {'Jackie': 176, 'Wilson': 185, 'Saersha': 165,'Roman': 185,'Abram': 169}
y = [(v, k) for k, v in x.items()]  # creates a list of tuples as (value, key) pair
y.sort(reverse = True)  # sorts the items in a list
# creates a dictionary with key as value from list(x) and value as a list of key from list(x)
z = {}
for a in y:
    if a[0] in z:
        z[a[0]].append(a[1])
    else:
        z[a[0]] = [a[1]]

print(z)
```

Shouldn't the output be:

```
{185: ['Wilson', 'Roman'], 176: ['Jackie'], 169: ['Abram'], 165: ['Saersha']}
```

Instead it is like this:

```
{176: ['Jackie'], 185: ['Wilson', 'Roman'], 165: ['Saersha'], 169: ['Abram']}
```

Comment: Sure? Not when I execute it...

Comment: By the way check out defaultdicts for use cases like this.

Comment: Why does it matter ? Ordering is not a problem in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using an older version of python where dictionaries do not preserve ordering. Try using `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict` and this will solve your issue as that data structure is guaranteed to preserve insertion ordering even in older versions of the language and over the other implementations of the language that don't have the ordered `dict`.